# If a player completes all their routes, are they required to pick up new destination cards even if the game is almost finished?

Tags: ticket-to-ride, ticket-to-ride-europe

Let's say Player 1 has just finished playing all their trains and everyone is now taking their final turn. Suppose Player 2 completed all their routes on their previous turn. Is Player 2 still required pick up 3 new destination cards and keep at least 1? Doing so will cost Player 2 points unless Player 2 had previously completed one of these new routes earlier in the game.

Would it be possible in this situation to allow Player 2 to pick up 3 new destination cards and have the option of discarding all three of them should they find keeping any would cost them points?

Comment: This question was was originally just tagged [tag:ticket-to-ride-europe], but the answers apply across all versions of TTR, so I added [tag:ticket-to-ride]

Comment: Also a duplicate; https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/21272/is-it-mandatory-to-draw-more-destination-tickets-when-they-are-completed?noredirect=1&lq=1... not sure which one should be closed.

Answer (score 12):

According to the rules (available [here](http://www.daysofwonder.com/tickettoride/en/europe/rules/)) you are **not** required to pick new destination cards when you complete the ones in your hand.

Player 2 can simply perform one of the other actions for his last turn, e.g. drawing train cards.

Answer (score 8):

No, definitely not. You are never required to draw Destinations Tickets except during setup. It seems to me you don't realize one can claim routes even without Destination Tickets<sup>[1]</sup>. There's a good chance P2 might have the Train Cards to claim a one- or two-train route for the one or two points it gives.

If P2 can't claim any routes, then they should draw some Train Cards. While P2 could draw Destinations Tickets hoping to draw one they have already completed, that's far too likely to cost them points.

---

1. I've played games where I've kept my Destination Tickets to a minimum to focus on getting Stockholm-Petrograd (21 points) and Budapest-Kyiv (15 points).